# Bad format returned by Stack Exchange API, not GZip?

Tags: support, api, c#, .net, gzip

I'm attempting to request some information using the Stack Exchange API. Supposedly, it returns responses compress with GZip. Using Microsoft's `System.IO.Compression.GZipStream` or `Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream`, I'm always told the data is not in GZip format... Even though the response's Content-Encoding is "gzip".

I've also written the bytes from the response to a file and transferred it to a Linux box and attempted to gunzip it, but that also returned an error.

What am I doing wrong? I am sending `Accept-Encoding: gzip` and getting `Content-Encoding: gzip`...

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException - The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.
```

Here's is runnable code:

```
internal static readonly string TagSearchUrl = "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/tags?site=stackoverflow&inname=c#";

internal static string FetchURL(string url) {
    var req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip";
    var resp = req.GetResponse();
    var contentType = resp.Headers["Content-Encoding"];
    var responseString = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    return UnZip(responseString);
}

public static string UnZip(string value) {
    byte[] byteArray = StringToByteArray(value);

    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray)) {

        //using (var sr = new Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream(ms, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Decompress)) {
        using (var sr = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)) {
            byteArray = new byte[byteArray.Length];
            try {
                var count = sr.Read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }
            finally {
                sr.Close();
                ms.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    return ByteArrayToString(byteArray);
}

private static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] byteArray) {
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
}

private static byte[] StringToByteArray(string value) {
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're treating the response as a UTF-8 encoded string. That's bound to fail with binary data like GZip. A quick fix is to use `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` instead of `UTF8` in `StringToByteArray`, and also pass this encoding to the `StreamReader` constructor in `FetchURL`.

That encoding maps bytes to codepoints one-to-one; see [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6644143/115866).

A cleaner way would be to not switch back and forth between unicode characters (`string`, `StreamReader`) and binary data (`byte[]`, `MemoryStream`) in the first place. Until you have unzipped the data, it does not constitute a "string" in any meaningful way.

Comment: The response has a `ContentType` of `application/json; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: I was able to get it to work. Using UTF-8 encoding works fine. I had to change StreamReader and now work with `byte[]`s *only* until after I've unzipped the response.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. Of course the JSON is UTF8-encoded. But treating the raw gzip data as UTF8 is what makes no sense.